# .net parallel computing on a computer cluster

Tags: .net, parallel-processing

I'm running some simulations using Task Parallel Library on .net 4. These simulations run well as parallel on my i7 cpu machine.

If i want to utilize other idle PCs too, then what kind of tool or library should I use?
Can TPL use other machines' resources if i properly set up? Or should I use something like MPI?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, TPL is not intended for distributed computing in its current implementation, so you will have to look at MPI or something else.